# select command in mysql doesnot return any row

Tags: php, mysql

i created a database using the command

```
CREATE TABLE login_table2(user_name VARCHAR(32), first_name VARCHAR(32), 
last_name VARCHAR(32), password VARCHAR(64));
```

then i inserted a data using command

```
INSERT INTO login_table2(user_name ,first_name , last_name , password ) 
VALUES('ramya', 'ramya', 'muthu', 'India');
```

the data got inserted into the table.
then i inserted another set of data using command

```
 INSERT INTO login_table2(user_name ,first_name , last_name , password ) 
    VALUES('jeyshree', 'jey', 'shree', 'India');
```

the data got inserted into the table too.
then i gave the command

```
SELECT first_name FROM login_table2;
```

the command displayed all the first_ name in the table.
however when i gave the command

```
 SELECT password FROM login_table2 WHERE user_name = 'ramya';
```

it does not fetch anything though the entry exist in the table.mention where i am going wrong.awaiting your reply.

Comment: nevermind, disregard this

Comment: what is the result of the `select * from login_table2;` ?

Answer (score 5):

try using

```
  SELECT databasename.first_name FROM login_table2;
```

or using all

```
  SELECT * FROM login_table2;
```

the [ * ] should works

Answer (score 5):

the code you are using looks fine to me

try using this in the end of the query

```
 or die (mysql_error());
```

to see what's the error within the query

---

example

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT password FROM login_table2 WHERE user_name = 'ramya'"); or die  (mysql_error());
```

---

and did you use after querying the table

```
 mysql_fetch_object($query);
```

Answer (score 2):

`password` is a keyword in MySQL. You can not directly use it in SQL query.

Try escaping it with apostrophe:

```
SELECT `password` FROM login_table2 WHERE user_name like 'ramya';
```

Comment: `password` may be a 'keyword', but it is NOT a `reserved word`. The use of backticks is redundant.

Answer (score 2):

you have to use a backtik for password.

> SELECT `password` FROM login_table2 WHERE user_name = 'ramya';

Refer this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-user.html

Answer (score 1):

This actually works fine for me. [Here is the SQLfiddle that I created.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2cc6b/2) One thing that I would suggest is that you might want to use "WHERE user_name like 'ramya'" instead.

Comment: what difference will that syntax make in this point? you haven't even included wildcards

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It seems to actually be better to use the '=' instead. I thought that '=' would be case-sensitive; however, I was incorrect. Learned something new today.

Answer (score 1):

try out this

```
SELECT password FROM login_table2 WHERE user_name like 'ramya';
```